# Why is this eigenvalue problem solved by $\phi(r) = J_v(\alpha r)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, recurrence-relations, eigenfunctions

I can't seem to see how the bessel function $J_v(ar)$ solves the problem. The eigenvalue problem has an $\alpha^ 2\phi(r)$ term

Ive tried writing $x = \alpha r$ in the expression for $J$ but cant seem to get it to work out

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By substituting $\alpha r$ for $r$ in the first display we obtain
$$
J''_{\nu}(\alpha r) + \frac{1}{\alpha r} J'_{\nu}(\alpha r) + \Bigr(1 - \frac{\nu^2}{\alpha^2 r^2}\Bigr) J_{\nu}(\alpha r) = 0,
$$
so, after multiplying both sides by $\alpha^2$,
$$
\alpha^2 J''_{\nu}(\alpha r) + \frac{\alpha}{r} J'_{\nu}(\alpha r) + \Bigr(\alpha^2 - \frac{\nu^2}{r^2}\Bigr) J_{\nu}(\alpha r) = 0.
$$
But $\phi'(r) = \alpha J'_{\nu}(\alpha r)$ and $\phi''(r) = \alpha^2 J'_{\nu}(\alpha r)$.

Comment: My mistake was not realising to multiply by $\alpha^2$